# Check and compare log files in a directory/folder before process the file in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, compare, glob

I would like to seek mechanism to check files in a directory before continue with the next process. I don't have any solution for now. At the moment the script is read and parse latest file (log files is generated every 4 hours) in a directory. I use glob to list the files and get the latest file. Thn proceed with the next process based on 'latestFile'

```
fileDir = '/my/dir/log//filegen_*.json' 
listFile = glob.glob(fileDir)
latestFile = max(listFile, key=os.path.getctime)

process parse latestFile ...
```

I would like to improve the script so that it able to check the files in the directory before read/parse. For example each time the file is process it will log the file name (each file name is genrated and differentiate by date/time) and before it execute another latest file it will check if the latest file is really latest file that generated 4 hours ago or its an old file that have been read before. If old file stop the process and log warning.

Thank you for you help and advise.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Hi sir, not really a problem. The current script work fine for now. I just need to add some mechanism in the script that able to check files names and to avoid to process the same file. This could happen if new file fail to be created in the directory and the script will process the same file again and again...hope its clear.

Comment: It is pretty clear what your requirement is but what are you having a problem with?

Comment: problem that i might get is the script will process the same files and the process of data (save to db) will be duplicates in the db.